# How to find the next indexed item in an $.each array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to simply find the next element in my $.each array :

```
$.each($(".datenumber"), function(idx, item){
    alert( item[idx + 1] );
});
```

But this returns undefined for all the instances. If I just find `item` with no `idx` call, it calls the item properly.

Then if I do this :

```
$.each($(".datenumber"), function(idx, item){
    alert( $(item[idx + 1]) );
  });
```

It's always an object **even** for the last object which *should* return a null object since nothing would be after the last item. Also, none of these objects returns have any value or anything in them..

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.each($(".datenumber"), function(idx, item){
    alert( $(".datenumber")[idx + 1] );
});
```

Or better yet, cache it:

```
var $datenumber = $(".datenumber");

$.each($datenumber, function(idx, item){
    alert( $datenumber[idx + 1] );
});
```

Comment: That will cause jQuery to find all `.datenumber` on every loop... should cache that to a variable first.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Javascript `for` instead:

```
var elements = $('.datenumber').get( );
for( var i in elements ) {
    alert( $(elements[i + 1]) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Incorrectly using $.each for jquery object
http://api.jquery.com/each/

There is use case for $.each for object literals and arrays as $.each as well

syntax is

```
 $(selector).each.....


$(".datenumber").each( function(idx, item){
    var $next= $(this).next()
    if( $next().length){                            
        // do something with next           
    }
});
```

Alert won't do much good on an object, log to console instead. Will get a lot more information